# How to update $_file in this approach?

Tags: php, mysql, file, sql-update

how to update the current image profile. in photos folder.

here's what I'm using in uploading image in form.

```
<input type="file" name="image" class="ed" id="inputFile"  required>
```

here's my approach I created. its working if I didnt include the image in UPDATE query.

```
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$avatar="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$app = $_POST['app_id1'];
mysql_query("UPDATE cswd_records set name ='".$_POST['name']. "', age ='".$_POST['age']. "', bdate ='".$_POST['bdate']."', bplace ='".$_POST['bplace']."', educ ='".$_POST['educ']."', occu ='".$_POST['occu']."', inc ='".$_POST['inc']."', status ='".$_POST['status']."', addr ='".$_POST['addr']."', contact ='".$_POST['contact']."', photo ='$avatar',  probpres ='".$_POST['probpres']."', findings ='".$_POST['findings']."', evalreco ='".$_POST['evalreco']."', recom ='".$_POST['recom']."', lastdate =  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p')  WHERE app_id = '".$_POST['app_id1']."'");
```

but If I added I got some error.

> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\admin\saveupdaterecord.php on line 28
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\admin\saveupdaterecord.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\admin\saveupdaterecord.php on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\admin\saveupdaterecord.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\admin\saveupdaterecord.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\admin\saveupdaterecord.php on line 31

Comment: have u put enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form??

Comment: Please give us your total form code.

Comment: I fixed it thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207155/editing-image-by-using-input-file-type